# Used mysql command instead of mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I wanted to backup my MySQL database and I accidentally used `mysql` command instead of `mysqldump`. So I executed:

```
/usr/local/mysql5/bin/mysql -u db_username -p db_name > db_backup.sql
```

Instead of:

```
/usr/local/mysql5/bin/mysqldump -u db_username -p db_name > db_backup.sql
```

I was ask for the db password and nothing happened after. The process just didn't react and I had to kill it. Could this have damaged my database?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The mysql command is an interactive shell, in which you can execute SQL-Queries (like `SELECT * FROM accounts;` ). Without shell redirection, it will print out a prompt (after entering the password), which indicates that you can enter a command now. This command is being read from stdin; without a quit command (or `<Ctrl>` + `<D>` to indicate EOF) this command obviously waits for input.

Without any input, the database is unaltered, and therefore no harm is being done to the database (you only killed a client to access the database, not the database server process!)